# Creating a new column that has continuous sequence and rep based on multiple column values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm currently in a bit of a rut when it comes to R coding. I have been trying to use mutate, seq, and rep functions to generate a new column that iterates over multiple column values and different conditionals, but it has not come out correct. I have a few snippet of my data below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

lipidData <- data.frame("Type"=c(rep("LDL",5),rep("HDL",5)),
                        "featureID"=c(12,12,12,12,13,13,14,15,16,17),
                        "featureID2"=c(21,22,23,26,31,31,31,31,38,40))
lipidWrong <- lipidData %>%
group_by(Type,featureID) %>% 
group_by(Type,featureID2) %>% 
mutate(lipidName=paste0(rep("lipid",n()),"_",seq(1,n())))
lipidWrong
  Type  featureID featureID2 lipidName
   <fct>     <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>    
 1 LDL          12         21 lipid_1  
 2 LDL          12         22 lipid_1  
 3 LDL          12         23 lipid_1  
 4 LDL          12         26 lipid_1  
 5 LDL          13         31 lipid_1  
 6 HDL          13         31 lipid_1  
 7 HDL          14         31 lipid_2  
 8 HDL          15         31 lipid_3  
 9 HDL          16         38 lipid_1  
10 HDL          17         40 lipid_1
```

Instead of that incorrect data table, I would like to have the lipidName be grouped by Type and featureID and then looking at Type feature ID2. If they have the same type and featureID, then count them as the same lipid for lipidName. If they have the same type and featureID2, then count them as the same lipid for lipidName. Since my real dataset includes >100,000 lines, it would be great to know how to sequence the numbers over the entire dataset and not just the n() results from group_by.

I would like to see my results as:

```
lipidCorrect
   Type featureID featureID2 lipidName
1   LDL        12         21   lipid_1 # same type and featureID
2   LDL        12         22   lipid_1 # same type and featureID
3   LDL        12         23   lipid_1 # same type and featureID
4   LDL        12         26   lipid_1 # same type and featureID
5   LDL        13         31   lipid_2 # although featureID is the same with row6, it has a different type
6   HDL        13         31   lipid_3 # same type and featureID2
7   HDL        14         31   lipid_3 # same type and featureID2
8   HDL        15         31   lipid_3 # same type and featureID2
9   HDL        16         38   lipid_4 
10  HDL        17         40   lipid_5
```

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong with my group_by() and mutate(), and also please let me know of a better way to produce the desired results.

Thanks!

Comment: Making sure I understand: Two rows will have the same `lipidName` if they (a) have the same type AND (b) either have the same `featureID` or the same `featureID2`. Is that correct?

Comment: Note: The second `group_by()` will *override* your the first grouping.

Comment: Your example data shows all lipids of the same name sharing *either* featureID 1 or 2, but are chains possible? E.g., (all within the same type, and abbreviating `featureID` as "`fID`"),  X has `fID = 30, fID2 = 50`, Y has `fID = 31, fID2 = 50`, Z has `fID = 31, fID2 = 51`, do they all have the same lipid name even though X is only connected to Z via Y?

Comment: If I'm right in my first comment and chains are possible, then this is a graph theory problem - features are nodes, and your data is an edgelist. Use `igraph` to find the connected subgraphs (by group), and each connected subgraph gets a unique `lipidName`.

Comment: @GregorThomas. Yes, they should have the same lipid name if they have the same type and featureID or same type and same featureID2

Comment: @GregorThomas For example, if X is LDL and fID=50, and Y is LDL and fID = 50, then the lipid name for both of them should be the same. X's lipidName = lipid_1 and Y's lipidName = lipid_2 but the count after "_" should iterate over the entire dataset.

Comment: I'm confused - you say "the lipid name for both of them should be the same", but then say "X's lipidName = lipid_1 and Y's lipidName = lipid_2", which looks like different names. And you don't mention Z, which is the crux of my question...

Comment: @GregorThomas Since fID and fID2 are ordered and fID does not equal fID2 in any instances, Z would have to be a different lipidName since X and Y grouping based on fID2 has been established first. It is like the first lipids to make a group based on type and fID or fID2 gets priority. If Z does not have the same fID2 with X and Y then it gets a different name.

Comment: @HarperFauni in my example Z has the same fid2 as Y, and Y has the same fid as X.

Comment: @GregorThomas There's a grouping priority, if grouping happened first with fID, then even if a lipidA has the same fID2 as the previous lipid, then lipidA would have a different name since grouping by fID happened first.

Comment: @GregorThomas I think it would be better to think of my data into chunks. A chunk can contain any number of lines. If chunkA was grouped by fID first, then even if the last row of chunkA and the first row of chunkB have the same fID2, then there would be a change of names from the last row of chunkA and the first row of chunkB. If chunkB had the same fID2, then even if the last row of chunkB and the first row of chunkC have the same fID, then there would also be a change in names from the last row of chunkB and the first row of chunkC.

Comment: @gregorthomas What I'm trying to say is that chaining is not allowed.

Comment: Great, nice and clear about the chains. My current understanding: First, group by type and fID1,  assign `lipidNames` to all groups *with more than 1 row*, with all rows within each group getting the same name, and the names iterate the number after the `_` between groups. THEN group by type and fID2 and repeat the process *only for those rows that don't already have `lipidNames`*. Does this sound right?

Comment: @GregorThomas Sorry for the late response! That's correct. First group by type and fID, anything that's unique (just one row for a specific type and fID) and to all groups with more than 1 row, within each group getting the same name. Then grouped by type and fID2. When you look at lipidCorrect, when you group by type and fID, it should look like lipidCorrect[1:5,].

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly (using the nice clarifying questions and comments by @Gregor Thomas), a (clumsy) solution based in the tidyverse could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

lipidData %>%
  group_by(Type, featureID) %>%
  mutate(lipidGroup1 = +(n() > 1)) %>%
  group_by(Type, featureID2) %>%
  mutate(lipidGroup2 = +(n() > 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(lipidGroup3 = +(lipidGroup1 == 0 & lipidGroup2 == 0)) %>%
  group_by(Type, featureID) %>%
  mutate(lipidGroup1 = if_else(n() > 1 & row_number() == min(row.names(.)), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Type, featureID2) %>%
  mutate(lipidGroup2 = if_else(n() > 1 & row_number() == min(row.names(.)), 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(lipidName = str_c('lipid_', cumsum(lipidGroup1 + lipidGroup2 + lipidGroup3))) %>%
  select(-starts_with('lipidGroup'))

#    Type  featureID featureID2 lipidName
#    <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>    
#  1 LDL          12         21 lipid_1  
#  2 LDL          12         22 lipid_1  
#  3 LDL          12         23 lipid_1  
#  4 LDL          12         26 lipid_1  
#  5 LDL          13         31 lipid_2  
#  6 HDL          13         31 lipid_3  
#  7 HDL          14         31 lipid_3  
#  8 HDL          15         31 lipid_3  
#  9 HDL          16         38 lipid_4  
# 10 HDL          17         40 lipid_5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using a helper variable to keep track of which grouping generates unique IDs, and then transforms that into the final variable:

```
lipidData %>%
  group_by(Type, featureID) %>% 
  mutate(
    name_id = case_when(n() > 1 ~ paste("fid1", cur_group_id()), TRUE ~ NA_character_)
  ) %>%
  group_by(Type,featureID2) %>% 
  mutate(
    name_id = case_when(is.na(name_id) ~ paste("fid2", cur_group_id()), TRUE ~ name_id)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    lipidName = paste("lipid", as.integer(factor(name_id, levels = unique(name_id))), sep = "_")
  ) %>%
  select(-name_id)
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    Type  featureID featureID2 lipidName
#    <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>    
#  1 LDL          12         21 lipid_1  
#  2 LDL          12         22 lipid_1  
#  3 LDL          12         23 lipid_1  
#  4 LDL          12         26 lipid_1  
#  5 LDL          13         31 lipid_2  
#  6 HDL          13         31 lipid_3  
#  7 HDL          14         31 lipid_3  
#  8 HDL          15         31 lipid_3  
#  9 HDL          16         38 lipid_4  
# 10 HDL          17         40 lipid_5
```